Php Content-Length header not send
I'm facing an issue since few days with my download file feature.
Content-Length is not set anymore and my XMLHttpRequest progress event function doesn't get lengthComputable correctly. My apache server is 2.4.61
<?php
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $nomFichier);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($cheminFichier));

function update_progress(e, elProgress) {
  if (e.lengthComputable) {
    var percentage = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
    
    if (elProgress) {
      var elProgress = jQuery(elProgress);
      elProgress.find('.progressBar').css('width', percentage + '%');
      elProgress.parent(".linkDetails").find('.progressPercent').html(percentage + '%');
    } else {
      jQuery(".progressBar").css('width', percentage + '%');
      jQuery(".progressPercent").html(percentage + '%');
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Unable to compute progress information since the total size is unknown");
  }
}

File path is set up correctly, filesize return the right size but Content-lenght is not set.
However I saw a new header Transfer-Encoding: chunked.
After reading some posts around internet I saw that this is part of HTTP specs and it's because Content-lenght is not set, but it is.
Actually the only workaround that I've found is to add a custom header Alternate-Content-Lenght and use it to update the progress bar percent value.
How can I continue to use Content-Lenght and not chunk of my file to be downloaded ?

"this is part of HTTP specs and it's because Content-lenght is not set" - no, the other way around - when chunked transfer encoding is used, then the Content-Length header gets omitted.

After talk with sysadmin it appears that the new version of Apache causing the issue.
Here is a part of the change log :
SECURITY: CVE-2024-24795: Apache HTTP Server: HTTP Response
     Splitting in multiple modules (cve.mitre.org)
     HTTP Response splitting in multiple modules in Apache HTTP
     Server allows an attacker that can inject malicious response
     headers into backend applications to cause an HTTP
     desynchronization attack.

     After this change, CGI-like scripts cannot set Transfer-Encoding
     or Content-Length headers.  To restore the ability to set Content-Length
     header, set per-request environment variable 'ap_trust_cgilike_cl' to any
     non-empty value.

So you have to use a custom header to handle content-lenght OR use somme conf like
SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.php$" ap_trust_cgilike_cl

But this re-opens the security implication that has just been closed ...

Sure but this is absolutely temporary solution as for now I have no idea how to retrieve the value of lengthComputable.
